# How to update value of font-size for header in Quill Editor in Angular project

Tags: angular, quill, ngx-quill

I have a quill editor in my angular project.
And all almost done, but I need update font size for H1 for 18px.
In the theme it mapped to 2em (~26px) 
I have try a lot of css selectors but cant find out right selector

```
<quill-editor placeholder="Text" [modules]="quillConfig" formControlName="text" [style]="{height: '250px'}">
     </quill-editor>

  <div class="quill-toolbar">
    <span class="ql-formats">
      <button class="ql-bold"></button>
      <button class="ql-italic"></button>
      <button class="ql-underline"></button>
      <button class="ql-header" value="1"></button>
    </span>

    <span class="ql-formats">
      <button class="ql-list" value="ordered"></button>
      <button class="ql-list" value="bullet"></button>
    </span>

    <span class="ql-formats">
      <button class="ql-link"></button>
      <button class="ql-image"></button>
      <button class="ql-video"></button>
    </span>
  </div>

quillConfig = {
    toolbar: '.quill-toolbar'
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use `::ng-deep`

**CSS**

```
::ng-deep .ql-snow .ql-editor h1 {
    font-size: 18px;
}
```

**SCSS**

```
::ng-deep {
   .ql-snow .ql-editor h1 {
    font-size: 18px;
   }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I have spent several days! You saved me!

Answer (score 3):

**Update:**

In **2019**, all I needed to do was add an `!important` flag to the HTML. No need to use `::ng-deep`. The rest is the same

For example:

```
   .ql-snow .ql-editor h1 {
       font-size: 18px !important;
   }
```

Hope this helps someone